# Como atualizar os dados ao mudar de componente Angular

Tags: angular, router

Basicamente meus dados são atualizados, porém quando vou para outro componente que mostra estes dados, eles ainda estão desatualizados. Tenho de ir para outro componente e voltar novamente para atualizar eles.

Tentei utilizar a função `this.router.navigateByUrl('/sites');` porém ela não atualiza os dados. Aparentemente o `ngOnInit` é chamado porém os dados se mantêm iguais nesta primeira chamada.

`ngOnInit` que deve atualizar:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.es.getAllDocuments(ShowSitesComponent.INDEX, ShowSitesComponent.TYPE).then(
      response => {
        this.siteSources = response.hits.hits;
        this.sizeOfSites = this.siteSources.length;
        console.log("This is the response:", this.siteSources);
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Show Site Completed!');
      });
  }
```

Fiz um teste para chamar este `ngOnInit` na outra função, independentemente da quantidade de vezes que eu chame este `ngOnInit` na outra função o valor não é atualizado, agora se eu clicar em um `button` com um `routerLink`, ele atualiza o valor.

Esta é a função que volta para o outro componente.

```
siteCreated(success: Boolean) {
    if (success) {
      let message = "Site adicionado, veja o log para mais informações";
      let action = "Ok";
      this.resetForm();
      this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
        duration: 5000,
      });
      this.showSites.ngOnInit();
      this.router.navigate(['/sites']); //O estranho é que isso não atualiza o valor
    } else if (!success) {
      let message = "Erro na Criação do Site";
      let action = "Ok";
      this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
        duration: 5000,
      });
    }
  }
```

O button que atualiza o componente é este:

```
 <a routerLink="" style="text-decoration: none; color: white" routerLinkActive="active"><button
        mat-raised-button>Página Inicial</button></a>
```

Acho bem estranho este botão atualizar o dado e o `this.router.navigateByUrl('/sites');` não funciona, tecnicamente eles não são a mesma coisa?

Acredito que tem algo a ver com `promises`, mas não consegui achar nenhuma solução para isto.

Comment: posta o seu codigo

Comment: Coloquei algumas partes para complementar

Comment: vc está tentando navigar pra mesma pagina?

Comment: não, eu estou em um componente diferente do que estou chamando no router

Comment: voce pode criar um service singleton(forRoot) que cuida o state do seu objeto, e tambem pode usar o subject/subjectbehavior para que toda sua aplicacao reconheca que houve alteracao do seu objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muitas tentativas, consegui resolver utilizando o seguinte 'macete':

```
timer(1000).subscribe(x => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/Refresh', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>
         this.router.navigate(["sites"]));
    });
```

Basicamente com um `subscribe` eu vou para um componente `Refresh`, que é um componente vazio, e depois ele volta para o componente que eu quero mostrar os dados atualizados, o `timer` determina que após 1 segundo estes dados serão atualizados.

Se você quiser atualizar o dado constantemente, claro, sem chamar um router, porquê ele é um loop, você pode utilizar um `interval` no lugar do `timer`